# Ruby TCPServer sockets

Tags: ruby, tcpserver, tcpsocket

Maybe I've gotten my sockets programming way mixed up, but shouldn't something like this work?

```
srv = TCPServer.open(3333)
client = srv.accept

data = ""
while (tmp = client.recv(10))
    data += tmp
end
```

I've tried pretty much every other method of "getting" data from the client TCPSocket, but all of them hang and never break out of the loop (getc, gets, read, etc).  I feel like I'm forgetting something.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 8):

In order for the server to be well written you will need to either:

- Know in advance the amount of data that will be communicated: In this case you can use the method `read(size)` instead of `recv(size)`. `read` blocks until the total amount of bytes is received.
- Have a termination sequence: In this case you keep a loop on `recv` until you receive a sequence of bytes indicating the communication is over.
- Have the client closing the socket after finishing the communication: In this case `read` will return with partial data or with 0 and `recv` will return with 0 size data `data.empty?==true`.
- Defining a communication timeout: You can use the function `select` in order to get a timeout when no communication was done after a certain period of time. In which case you will close the socket and assume every data was communicated.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

Hmm, I keep doing this on stack overflow [answering my own questions].  Maybe it will help somebody else.  I found an easier way to go about doing what I was trying to do:

```
srv = TCPServer.open(3333)
client = srv.accept

data = ""
recv_length = 56
while (tmp = client.recv(recv_length))
    data += tmp
    break if tmp.length < recv_length
end
```

Comment: the last chunk in the sequence you wish to send might be exactly `recv_length` in size and the loop will run once more (error).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that can be written to the socket so that `client.recv(10)` returns nil or false.

Try:

```
srv = TCPServer.open(3333)
client = srv.accept

data = ""
while (tmp = client.recv(10) and tmp != 'QUIT')
    data += tmp
end
```